# dotenv file is not recognized by server nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my first mern stack project ever and i'm trying to push it to github.
i am using mongoose so i had to hide the login and pwd of my account i looked it up and found the .env solution.
I created a dot env file

```
#.env file
Port=5000
CONNECTION_URL=mongodb+srv://+++++++++@cluster0.p5v9c.mongodb.net/++++++?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

i ran npm i dot env

then i added import statement: `import dotenv from 'dotenv';`

and the problem seems to occur here,
i tried:
`dotenv.config();`, `require('dotenv').config();`, `require ('dotenv/config');`.

the code to of my index js if it helps to solve the solution  :

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
    
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

can anyone help me solve this up i would really appreciate it thank you ^^

Comment: "... i ran npm i dot env ..." if this is not a typo, then it should've been `npm i dotenv` (without spaces between `dot` and `env`)

Comment: You need to access connection url using process.env.CONNECTION_URL

Comment: https://github.com/ashishsah1000/FullStackCart/blob/main/backend/server.js have a look at this it may help you

Comment: and do look at your `package.json` file if `dotenv` package is installed

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky still the same problem

Comment: @IronGeek  i miss typed the post , i checked package.json it's all set :(

Answer (score 0):

After installing you do not need to import dotenv.
Remove the line:

> import dotenv from 'dotenv';

Include dotenv with just:

> require('dotenv').config()

Comment: Depends. Newer versions of node can use the import syntax, older need the commonjs require. Technically they're both considered "importing"